# How to include data files and directories that need to be changed or added with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The script needs to read from a .txt file with a list of items and based off that list, it creates a directory for each item. So just a simple `with open()` statement and then `os.mkdir()..`

The client will add account names to the txt file when they get new accounts, the program will create new directories for those new accounts. Files that are then placed in each directory for those accounts will get pandas stuff done to them and moved to an archive folder along with logging the events.
Since the program will be used by non-programmers, I'm using Pyinstaller.

When I go through the process, including the `--add-file` attribute, run the program, it says the txt file doesn't exist. I think I have an idea how to fix that but when I got the `os.mkdir` and `with open` statements to work by separating them out, it created them in the home folder and not the program folder. Path issue? And I only see documentation on how to include data files but not how to include *changeable* files.

Comment: ***"none of it works."***: This is not helpful. [Edit] your question and explain in detail.

Comment: ***"but not how to include changeable files. "***: It's not the job of pyinstaller. You can use the packed `.txt` only as starting template. You have to copy, **first and once**, from unpacked source to your working directory if it not exists yet and use this afterwards.